# How to pass a jenkins build after killing the java process on remote host

Tags: java, jenkins

I've requirement that I need to execute java command `java -jar xxxx.jar` on a remote host. I am able to run the java job on the remote host. But After sometime I need to kill the java process. So I've created an another job which kills the java PID. It kills the java process on the remote host successfully. But the jenkins job which is running the java jar is failing

```
[SSH] exit-status: -1
Build step 'Execute shell script on remote host using ssh' marked build as failure
[BFA] Scanning build for known causes...
[BFA] No failure causes found
[BFA] Done. 0s
No previous build found...
Finished: FAILURE
```

But I'm intentionally killing the java process on the remote host. How can I pass the jenkins build. If anyone have solution, please help me with this situation. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there no other way to convince your remote job to stop, other than killing the process, like having it periodically check for the existence of a file?  It's going to be difficult to exit gracefully when you're using OS functionality to kill the JVM.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ignore the error occurred in the remote ssh, you can use `|| true`

```
java -jar xxxx.jar || true
```

Comment: still the build failed. 
`[SSH] exit-status: -1
  Build step 'Execute shell script on remote host using ssh' marked build as  failure
  No previous build found...
  Finished: FAILURE`

Comment: Actually in the java command I use data file. so my  java command will look like this... `java   -jar load-behaviors.jar  -c test.csv` . I tried using your `||true` at the end of the comamnd --> `java   -jar load-behaviors.jar  -c test.csv || true` so after using this, I killed the java process from another job and again it failed with
`[SSH] exit-status: -1
 Build step 'Execute shell script on remote host using ssh' marked build as   failure
 No previous build found...
 Finished: FAILURE`

Answer (score 0):

i had same problem with you, in my case it fixed when i use

```
java -jar xxxx.jar || if [ $? -ne 1 ]; then true; fi
```

check if build not returned exit code 1 then it means "true"